# How to add List items in dom4j defaultDocument object?

Tags: java, json, xml, dom4j

I am trying to update the DefaultDocument object with List of objects.

The DefaultDocument object looks like this.

```
<page>
   <createdDate>2021-02-01T15:44:55.548Z</createdDate>
   <lastModifiedDate>2021-02-02T13:54:52.371Z</lastModifiedDate>
   <summary>Sample Summary</summary>
   <title>Title</title>
</page>
```

I have list of keys and values as shown below.

```
List<String> list = myList // Contains following values

[
{
"city" : "london",
"image" : { "key" : "someKey", "description" : "some description" },
"title" : "UK"
}
]
```

Im trying to generate a defaultDocument as below.

```
<page>
   <createdDate>2021-02-01T15:44:55.548Z</createdDate>
   <lastModifiedDate>2021-02-02T13:54:52.371Z</lastModifiedDate>
   <summary>Sample Summary</summary>
   <title>Title</title>
   <items>
       <city>london</city>
       <image>
           <key>someKey</key>
           <description>some description</description>
       </image>
       <title>UK</title>
   </items>
</page>
```

Any advices would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this xml and underscore-java library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <element array="true">
    <city>london</city>
    <image>
      <key>someKey</key>
      <description>some description</description>
    </image>
    <title>UK</title>
  </element>
</root>
```